# How to migrate the Symfony demo app from sqlite to pdo_mysql

Tags: sqlite, pdo, symfony, database-migration

I've just installed Symfony demo and it works like a charm. Then I was wondering why there is no question in the process of installing it? and I found that it uses a `blog.sqlite` file for its posts.

My question is how can I migrate from `sqlite` to `pdo_mysql` and what are necessary steps?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This demo application uses an embedded SQLite database to simplify setup, if you don't want to use SQLite, change the URL in `parameters.yml` or set the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable.

MySQL example:

```
# app/config/parameters.yml
parameters:
    env(DATABASE_URL): 'mysql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony_demo'
```

Note: Make sure to use the correct `user` and `pass` credentials to connect to DB server.

You can also create the database and load the sample data from the command line:

```
$ cd symfony-demo/
$ php bin/console doctrine:database:create
$ php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
$ php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.